# How to show My Cart link at top links

Tags: magento

I installed a template, and there is no My Cart link at top link.
This in `checkout.xml`:

```
    <reference name="top.links">
       <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">               
           <action method="addCartLink"></action>
           <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
       </block>
    </reference>
```

I want to show it with item quantity ex: My Cart(1)
Please help me!

Best regards,

Comment: you got a solution???

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is within the template file add this code:

```
$count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();
```

This will display the number of items in the cart. If you copy the template and layout files into your theme you should be able to add this in and get it working.